# Need difference - setTimeout(callback, 0) vs $(window).load

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

What's the difference between these?
Will event loop be formed after the page load got finished ?

Answer (score 0):

They are so different that it isn't really worth comparing them.

---

Binding an event handler to the load event will call that function when:

- The load event fires (which is after the page and all its non-async dependencies have loaded) **and**
- The event loop isn't busy with something else

---

Passing a function to `setTimeout` with a time of 0 will call that function when:

- 0ms have passed **and**
- The minimum timeout for the JS engine has passed **and**
- The event loop isn't busy with something else (which includes the script which called `setTimeout` in the first place